# Any way to identify make of internal hard disk?

Tags: hard-drive, windows-xp

Is there any way on Windows XP Pro to identify all the information about the internal hard disks installed (without opening the case)? In particular, their make, size, partitions, health.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**[HWiNFO](https://www.hwinfo.com/)**

> **In-depth Hardware Information**   From a quick overview unfolding into the depth of all hardware components. Always up-to date
>   supporting latest technologies and standards.
>
> **Real-Time System Monitoring**   Accurate monitoring of all system components for actual status and failure prediction. Customizable
>   interface with variety of options.
>
> **Extensive Reporting**   Multiple types of reports, status logging and interfacing with other tools or add-ons.

[image]

Answer (score 3):

The easiest way is to use the built-in tools that come with Windows.

Find **Administrative Tools**, go to **Computer Management** and choose **Disk Management**. You will see information about partitions and size, including health.

If you right click on the disk, choose **Properties**. There, you will see its complete name, which is actually the name of the manufacturer, hard disk model and type (in my case it's WDC - Western Digital, WD1200BEVS - a 120 GB Digital Scorpio SATA hard drive).

Comment: Too much messing around in Windows to get the info I want. The Windows interface to most system level details is pretty unfriendly

Comment: But then you don't need to install any 3rd party software and its associated risk of malware to find some info that you'll only use once.